# Debugging MVVMCross PCL in MonoAndroid projects (VS2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I'm developing some apps using the MvvmCross framework, and I'm having some problems with the debug of PCL's when running "Droid" projects in VS2010.

I've downloaded the sample apps from [GitHub/MvvmCross](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross) and tried to debug the PCL's through Droid projects. When the app his deployed in the device (emulator or physical), **no break points are hitted inside the PCL code. If I use a WP7 project, I'm able to debbug through the PCL code.**

I've got VS2010 and VS2010 installed. I've followed all the instructions in http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/mvvmcross-vnext-portable-class.html and http://jpobst.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/mono-for-android-portable-libraries-in.html.

I've searched for post related to this issue, and I've found nothing related to PCL debugging in VS2010.

I know thas this is a fairly vague post, but I'm just trying to find someone else that had this same problem, and hopefully beeing able to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the MonoDroid debugger often breaks - and the PCL support is obviously also 'nascent' at best.

Developers can help you with advice like 'make sure fast deployment and shared (debug) SDK is selected' but fundamentally you'll need to ask Xamarin for a fix.

My advice - log and pursue the problems with Xamarin through their forums, through bugzilla and through any customer support contract you have.

In the meantime without MonoDroid debugger, then it's back to WinRT and WP (and MonoTouch on Mac) for debugging your PCLs 
- or it's back to 'old skool' techniques like adding trace

Comment: I've tried with all that options and others, but it didn't work. I've allready made a new post in Xamarin dev center... i'll wait and see if i can get any feedback... i've been using some trace to help on debug, but as time goes by the WP/WinRT approach seems more viable (well..., it really depends the level of debug needed). thanks!

Comment: Good luck - my bug report has gone ignored since November - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8209 :(

Comment: Yes, i've seen your report. It's on my 'Favorites Bar'. Let's hope it's not forgotten...